# Error after updating AJAXControlToolkit.dll to version 15

Tags: webforms, devexpress, assemblies, ajaxcontroltoolkit, .net-assembly

Updated the AJAXControlToolkit.dll in an old ASP.NET 4.5.1 WebForms project and am now getting this error:

`Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.HoverMenuExtender' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.`

We have an old hover menu extender control in the page that is likely part of the problem:
`<ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="pnlCustomerOptE" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlCustomerAction" PopupPosition="Bottom" TargetControlID="custMenuBtn" PopDelay="200" />`

And a div with an image in it that acts like a button on the same page:

`<div class="hover-menu-button" id="custMenuBtn" runat="server">Customer 
<img src="~/App_Images/nav/arrow-down.gif" id="imgCustMenuArrow" runat="server" width="9" height="8" class="hover-menu-img" alt="" /></div>`

Why is this error occuring and how can I fix it? I am running Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

You can not fix it until v16.2 will be released: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/3